# After installing Jenkins I did not direceted to http://localhost:8080/

Tags: jenkins, devops

After I completed the installation process of Jenkins, I was not redirected to http://localhost:8080/ and when I entered the url manually in the browser, I received the following error:

> This site can’t be reached.

Comment: on what operating system? have you tried to restart? also if you are on windows, doubly check on `services.msc` (the services management interface) and see if the `Jenkins` service is running.

Comment: I am using the Windows 10.

Comment: @Bagus Tesa: Yes the Jenkins server is running.

Comment: @Bagus Tesa: After restarting still the http://locahost:8080/ is not reachable.

Comment: have you tried `127.0.0.1:8080` too? there are many reason for this problem to occur. [browser going nuts](https://superuser.com/a/649631) is one of it.

Comment: 127.0.0.1:8080 is also not working. Do I need Apache server as well?

Comment: first you should check if jenkins' `java.exe` process running in task manager - which it should given the service status is running. then, please [check currently open ports on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48199) and see if `8080` is properly open. also, if you have git for windows installed (or linux subsystem for windows, cygwin, mingw), try to reach the site using `curl` (e.g. `curl -X GET "localhost:8080"`) to ensure it wasnt the browser going nuts - you could try on another browser too.

Comment: I dont see jenkins running in the task manager. What can i do for it?
After running curl -X GET "localhost:8080" I got the:
$ curl -X GET "localhost:8080"
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:02 --:--:--     0
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 8080 after 2222 ms: Connection refused

Comment: i'm stumped, somehow jenkins doesn't run despite windows says its running properly. you should update your question with the information we have gathered. it helps people in telling where the exact problem lie. you have to be specific on your question as "[ask]" has mentioned.